# Protobuf.js .toObject() with .NET types

Tags: javascript, .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, protobuf.js

I'm using a combination of protobuf-net (server) and protobuf.js (browser client).

I have a .proto like this:

```
package Testy;
import "bcl.proto"; // schema for protobuf-net's handling of core .NET types

message Foo {
    optional int32 ID = 1 (default = 0);
    optional bcl.Decimal Bar = 2 (default = 0);
}
```

When I decode an incoming Foo ArrayBuffer and call .toObject() how do I plug in a bcl.Decimal converter?

```
var testyPackage = "package Testy; import ... (continued)";
var bclPackage = "package bcl; message TimeSpan ... (continued)",
    protoRoot = new protobuf.Root();
protobuf.parse(bclPackage, protoRoot);
protobuf.parse(testyPackage, protoRoot);

var buffer = new Uint8Array(someArrayBufferSomewhere..),
    msg = protoRoot.Testy.Foo.decode(buffer);


function convertsBclDecimalToNumber(bclDecimal) {
    ...
}

var obj = msg.toObject({Decimal: convertsBclDecimalToNumber}) //This won't work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I do it, but is this the way the library intended?

```
var x = protoRoot.Testy.Foo.decode(buffer);
protoRoot.lookup("bcl.Decimal").toObject = myBclDecimalConverterFunctionReference
return x.toObject();
```

Comment: There is no intended way to achieve this. Your solution looks good to me.

Comment: Glory be to you! Thanks dude.